# angular ng-hide with animate.css strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, animate.css, ng-hide

this example works fine until I click fast and multiple times on the check box. Then I can't hide the rectangle anymore. The animation completes fine, the rectangle fades out, then it becomes visible again when it should be hidden. Any idea why?

http://jsfiddle.net/sqDxL/2/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="hide" />hide</label> <br />
    {{hide}}<br />
   <div class="fade-in square" ng-hide="hide">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

// css
    .fade-in.ng-hide-remove { -webkit-animation:fadeIn 1s; animation:fadeIn 1s; }
    .fade-in.ng-hide-add{ -webkit-animation:fadeOut 1s; animation:fadeOut 1s;}
    .square {background: darkgreen; height: 200px; width:300px; }

// js
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.anim = 'fade-in';
        $scope.hide = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. 
I had to add:

```
.ng-hide {
    display:none!important;
}
```

and change

```
.fade-in.ng-hide-add { -webkit-animation:fadeOut 1s; animation:fadeOut 1s; display:block!important;}
```

to

```
.fade-in.ng-hide-add-active { -webkit-animation:fadeOut 1s; animation:fadeOut 1s; display:block!important;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sqDxL/4/

Comment: Adding ```display:none!important;``` fixed a flicker issue on a non-animating ```ng-hide``` for me. Thanks!

Comment: Your jsfiddle link no longer works.  Ashraf, can you fix this?  I am interested in your solution.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have deleted it by mistake. I tried to create a new fiddle for you but my solution no longer works :(
http://jsfiddle.net/ashraffayad/1xb4o85L/ 
Any way, in the end I decided to skip angular animation altogether and apply my animation manually.